# SASS: What is the cause of the error: "End of line expected"?

Tags: sass

I am currently learning Sass. I got a minor problem, I receive this error: "End of line expected". Why do I get this error and what can I do about it?

```
.admin-table tr: nth-child(odd) // Generates the error
 background-color: $white

.admin-table tr: nth-child(even) // Generates the error
 background-color: $white
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sass syntax you'll need to remove the spaces in `: nth-child)`, also a good idea to add semi-colons `;` to the end of each property

```
.admin-table tr:nth-child(odd)
  background-color: $white;


.admin-table tr:nth-child(even)
  background-color: $white;
```

For Scss syntax you'll additionally need to add braces

```
.admin-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: $white;
}


.admin-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: $white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take off the spaces betwen `tr:` and `nth-child` . Furthermore, add `;` at the end of each property as following :

```
.admin-table tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: $white;
}

.admin-table tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: $white;
}
```